# Need to create dynamic CSS names for buttons

Tags: templating, filter, css

This may not be the most efficient approach for this specific case but I'm trying to learn how this might be done for other similar problems I might run across in the future so bear with me here.

I have a Global that creates links to social media sites on my profile page. My fields include icon (asset), name (text), url (text), and color (color). I have included the following at the top of my template:

```
{% set buttonCSS %}
    {% for block in contactLinks.contactLinks.type("contactLink") %}
    .{{ block.contactLinkName | lower }}:hover {
        background-color: {{ block.buttonColor }}
    }
    {% endfor %}
{% endset %}

{% includeCss buttonCSS %}
```

This generates dynamic styles for each button at the top of my profile page so I can add links. My template then generates the links:

```
{% for block in contactLinks.contactLinks.type("contactLink") %}
<a href="{{ block.contactLinkUrl | entities }}" class="contact_link {{ block.contactLinkName | lower }}{% if loop.last %} last{% endif %}" target="_blank">
    <img src="{{ block.contactLinkIcon.first().url }}" class="contact_link_image" /><p class="contact_link_text">{{ block.contactLinkName }}</p>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, for the most part this works since social media sites tend to be one word but when I tried to use "Let's Talk" for my email link I run into problems with the CSS. What's the best way to strip the apostrophe and spaces from my class names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain filters to achieve what you want. [The example for the twig replace filter in the Craft docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#replace) shows this in action.

So you could replace:

```
{{ block.contactLinkName | lower }}
```

with:

```
{{ block.contactLinkName | lower | replace('/ /', '-') | replace("'","") }}
```

Comment: This worked for the most part. One of these days I'm going to learn RegEx but I was able to change the first replace to look for only spaces. As written this removes a lot more then just spaces. I'll look into a way to find punctuation and update this soon but for now this works.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the [slugify](https://gist.github.com/boboldehampsink/7354431) twig filter:

```
{{ block.contactLinkName | slugify }}
```

It will handle apostrophies, spaces, and anything else that might come along.

Comment: I believe you need to have the Slugify plugin installed to use this filter: http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/slugify

Comment: That certainly simplifies things. Still, I probably should learn RegEx.

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the twig replace

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html

```
{{ block.contactLinkName | replace({' ': -}) }}
```